# Not all groups syncing to linux machine with SSSD?

Tags: sssd

We have Active Directory synced to a linux server (centOS 7) via [sssd](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/) and notice that some groups that users are set as members of in AD do not show up on the sssd-enabled linux server.

Eg. I may create a group g1 in AD and set AD user user001 to be a member of that group, but when ssh'ing into the linux server and doing `id user001` the groups listed for the user do not include that newly created group.

```bsh
[sssd]
domains = co.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, pac

[domain/co.local]
ad_domain = co.local
krb5_realm = CO.LOCAL
auth_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = False
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_access_order = expire
ldap_account_expire_policy = ad
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = true
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
default_domain_suffix = co.local
enumerate = true
```

Looking at the logs for the sssd service, I see...

```bsh
[root@myserver~]# service sssd status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l sssd.service
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-21 17:25:19 HST; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 11677 (sssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─11677 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─11678 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain co.local --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─11679 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─11680 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─11681 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Feb 25 14:10:29 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:10:29 myserver.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][11678]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (KDC has no support for encryption type)
Feb 25 14:10:29 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:10:29 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:10:29 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:10:29 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 2
Feb 25 14:25:28 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:25:28 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:25:28 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 25 14:25:28 myserver.co.local sssd_be[11678]: GSSAPI client step 2
```

Looking at the logs in `/var/logs/sssd`, the most substantial looking thing I could find was...

```bsh
[root@hwdatalake ~]# cat /var/log/sssd/sssd_nss.log-20200224
(Sun Feb 16 04:17:11 2020) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
(Sun Feb 16 05:57:15 2020) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error 
...
...
...
(Tue Feb 18 09:38:59 2020) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
(Tue Feb 18 11:19:03 2020) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
(Tue Feb 18 12:59:06 2020) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
(Tue Feb 18 13:16:14 2020) [sssd[nss]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
(Tue Feb 18 19:41:24 2020) [sssd[nss]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
(Tue Feb 18 19:56:09 2020) [sssd[nss]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
(Wed Feb 19 12:27:30 2020) [sssd[nss]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
```

Anyone with more experience with sssd have ideas as to what could be happening here? Any debugging tips (No experience with sssd and am not the person who initially set it up on the server)?

Comment: Why are you looking at `sssd` if your machine was joined to AD with Samba?

Comment: @roaima (Assuming your referring to the `realmd_tags` setting) Not sure. Was not the one who set up sssd on the server. Will need to ask the person who did and look into the config settings meanings myself for clarification (but thanks for letting me know that's not normal).